# How to use atmosphere-spade-server in combination with atmosphere-pubsub.war

Tags: java, comet, atmosphere

I would like to play with atmosphere-spade-server.jar + pubsub.war. First of I have maven installed, but to be honest Maven is kind of new to me. Could please someone please explain me how to use it correctly.

What I have tried

1. Download atmosphere-spade-server + pubsub.war from there site.
2. `java -jar atmosphere-spade-server-0.6.0-20100329.142039-1.jar -a atmosphere-pubsub.war`
3. `curl http://localhost:8080/atmosphere-pubsub/myAtmosphereTopic`

   > `<html><body><h1>Resource Not> Found</h1></body></html>`

I would just have a guided tour of how to use Atmosphere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this discussion on the topic](http://atmosphere-users-mailling-list.2493822.n2.nabble.com/Playing-with-atmosphere-spade-server-atmosphere-pubsub-war-td5044687.html#a5046409). The Atmosphere repository for download is now with Sonatype. Grab the latest version there.